# How to debug "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" Swift error?

Tags: swift

I need the following code to run.

```
let illinois = College(name: "University od Illinois", location: "Urbana-Champaign", numberOfStudents: 35000, image: UIImage(named: "Default")!)

let missouri = College(name: "University of Missouri", location: "Columbia", numberOfStudents: 34658, image: UIImage(named: "MissuouriImage")!)

let iowa = College(name: "University of Iowa", location: "Iowa City", numberOfStudents: 31065, image: UIImage(named: "IowaImage")!)

colleges = [illinois, missouri, iowa]
```

In missouri it says EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0), here is an image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/euCg8.png

Comment: You should post snippets of your code. Otherwise it's very hard for us to help!

Comment: Check the name of you Missouri image, it looks like there's a typo.

Comment: Thanks Eric that was the problem mant thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This code is causing your crash:

```
UIImage(named: "MissuouriImage")!
```

Check that the image exists (it should probably be called "MissouriImage") and consider unwrapping your optional to make sure it exists:

```
if let missouriImage = UIImage(named: "MissuouriImage") {
    let missouri = College(name: "University of Missouri", location: "Columbia", numberOfStudents: 34658, image: missouriImage)
}
```